# Python: Network Spring Layout with different color nodes

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I create a spring layout network of the shortest path from a given node. In this case `firm1`. I want to have a different color for each degree of separation. For instance, all the first edge connecting `firm1` and the other firms, say `firm2` and `firm3`, I would like to change the node color of `firm2` and `firm3` (same color for both). Then all the firms connected from `firm2` and `firm3`, say `firm4` and `firm5` I want to change their node colors. But I don't know how to change the colors of the node for each degree of separation starting from `firm1`. Here's my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

graph = nx.Graph()
with open('C:\\file.txt') as f: #Here, I load a text file with two columns indicating the connections between each firm
    for line in f:
        tic_1, tic_2 = line.split()
        graph.add_edge(tic_1, tic_2)

paths_from_1 = nx.shortest_path(graph, "firm1") #I get the shortest path starting from firm1

x = pd.DataFrame(paths_from_1.values()) #I convert the dictionary of the shortest path into a dataframe


tic_0=x[0].tolist() #there are 7 columns in my dataframe x and I convert each columns into a list. tic_0 is a list of `firm1` string
tic_1=x[1].tolist() #tic_1 is list of all the firms directly connected to firm1
tic_2=x[2].tolist() #tic_2 are the firms indirectly connected to firm1 via the firms in tic_1
tic_3=x[3].tolist() #and so on...
tic_4=x[4].tolist()
tic_5=x[5].tolist()
tic_6=x[6].tolist()

l = len(tic_0)
graph = nx.Graph()

for i in range(len(tic_0)):
        graph.add_edge(tic_0[i], tic_1[i]) 
        graph.add_edge(tic_1[i], tic_2[i])
        graph.add_edge(tic_2[i], tic_3[i])
        graph.add_edge(tic_3[i], tic_4[i])
        graph.add_edge(tic_4[i], tic_5[i])
        graph.add_edge(tic_5[i], tic_6[i])

pos = nx.spring_layout(graph_short, iterations=200, k=)
nx.draw(graph_short, pos, font_size='6',)
plt.savefig("network.png")
plt.show()
```

How can I have different color nodes for each degree of separation? In other words, all the firms in `tic_1` should have a node that is blue, all the firms in `tic_2` has a yellow node color, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic way to do this is to run the shortest path length algorithm from a source node to assign the colors.  Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.balanced_tree(2,5)
length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=0)
nodelist,hops = zip(*length.items())
positions = nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog='twopi', root=0)
nx.draw(G, positions, nodelist = nodelist, node_color=hops, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could use

```
positions = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

instead.  I used the graphviz circo layout since it does a better job at drawing the balanced tree I used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like what I need but I have difficulties to link pygraphviz and graphviz. I installed both (windows) and I keep getting ` raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path."%prog)
ValueError: Program twopi not found in path.` ... I don't know which file to modify to link the path of the installed folder of graphviz. Any clue? Thank you

Comment: I know some people have PyGraphviz or Pydot working with Windows.  So it is possible - but I'm not familiar with how to install them correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21947989: code does not work for networkx 2.2; `# for networkx > 2 : positions = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog = 'twopi', root = 0)`